# How to turn off Hindi Language prediction in Google Chrome mobile?

Tags: languages

When I search something in google, I get a suggestion from google about its meaning and details in Hindi Language. I don't know whether it is based on some geo location or something. I neither know Hindi nor wanted to learn it.

Is there some ways in which I could turn this feature off? I don't know why google is suggesting something to me which I don't even know.

What I have already done:

1. Went to My Account
2. Under Language and input , selected English ( UK ) and My mother tongue ( Malayalam )
3. Saved the preference.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Open google website. At the bottom you will see setting.
Go to setting / search setting / region setting / change it to United States. Then you will not get Hindi version.

Answer (score -1):

Is this issue you face on the browser's site? Or app? You could always change the language from bottom...guess you've already tried this but wth hope your issue gets resolved soon [image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Please open Google app
2. Tap to more button (right)
3. Tab to settings
4. Tab to search language
5. Select or change your search language

Exuzme, I speaking English is weak .